no se abre la ventana con pygame
no se porque pero cuando pongo el siguiente código me sale lo siguiente:
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pygame' has no attribute 'init' (most likely due to a circular import)
import pygame

ANCHO = 1000
ALTO = 800
VENTANA = pygame.display.set_mode([ANCHO, ALTO])

jugando = True

while jugando:
    eventos = pygame.event.get()

    for evento in eventos:
        if evento.type == pygame.QUIT:
            jugando = False

    pygame.display.update()

quit()


¿Por casualidad no habrás llamado a tu módulo pygame.py (o tienes otro archivo/directorio con ese nombre en la misma carpeta)? No nombres a tus módulos o paquetes con el mismo nombre de módulos/paquetes de terceros instalados o de la propia stdlib de Python, los módulo en el CWD tienen prioridad en el orden de resolución de los imports. Mirate esta otra pregunta: Error en import: module 'random' has no attribute 'randint', simplemente renombra el archivo/directorio, estoy bastante seguro que es este tu problema, pero en caso contrario comenta.

Gracias por la ayuda, resulta que tenia que crear una carpeta aparte, ya que había creado el archivo en la carpeta Visual Studio Code. Muchas gracias, ahora funciona perfectamente.
